# Dependent parameters in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Goodnight.
I tell you my problem. I have a report with several parameters, among them, these two: "@paramMarca" and "@paramModelo" both of the text type.
In the "default" field of the @paramModelo I have a query to a dataset that has the following query:

```
select modelo from vehiculos where marca=[@paramMarca]
```

So when I run the report, filling in the "marca" field brings me a list of models from the "vehicles" table. So far so good...
The issue is that it forces me to load a data in "marca" because, if I don't do it, the "modelo" field remains with the legend: <"select a value"> and it doesn't let me execute the query.

What I tried to do in the "modelo" dataset, is the following:

```
if (@paramMarca <> '')
begin
   select modelo from vehiculos where marca=[@paramMarca]
end
else
begin
   select ''
end
```

But this doesn't bring me the default '' value, instead it's left with the legend <"select a value">. The issue is that the operator is not always going to load the "marca" data. How could I do?
I'm out of ideas.

From already thank you very much.
Best regards.

Raulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `@paramMarca` parameter is set to a default of ''.

To get the `@paramModelo` parameter to also default to '' we just need to add that as an option to the query for the parameter:

```
select modelo as Value, modeloDescription as Description 
from vehiculos 
where marca=[@paramMarca]
union all
select '' as Value, '*All Modelo*' as Description
```

Side note: I've added a description field for better display purposes - hook these up in your parameter.

Then set the default for the `@paramModelo` parameter to '' and this should work.

Note that if these are the only two parameters, then because they have valid default values this will cause the report to instantly run for all values which may be time consuming depending on your datsaset.

Comment: Thanks Chris! It worked!
A cordial greeting.